# How to RegEx between values that can be multiline or singleline

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I have a long text from which I need to extract data. I am trying to use RegEx but with little success. I did my research, tried a lot of things, but it is not working.

The pattern should:

- Find the string: "Adónem számlaszáma: "
- Return the account number after that
- Go backwards UNTIL the first word with 3 digits
- Return that 3-letter code
- Return the text between this code and the first string

Part of the text:

```
Időszak: 2021.01.01-2021.11.24
/
101 Társasági adó   Adónem számlaszáma: 10032000-01076019
2021.01.01.
Nyitóegyenleg
```

Pattern used:

```
*Flags used: global, single line*

(\b\d\d\d\b)( .*?)Adónem számlaszáma: (.*?)\n
```

Match is good:

[image: match1]

Another part of the text:

```
-13 000


    101 adónemen többlet:   5 000 Ft
104 Általános forgalmi adó  Adónem számlaszáma: 10032000-01076868
```

Same pattern used.

Match is not good:

[image: match2]

This is the full file I am working with: [samplefile.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FKD1Mf-AVeXz87YgL3uJKJivxyH5V3KN/view?usp=sharing)

What am I missing? I have the lazy quantifier, dot matches newline etc... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you do not need to match across lines? See `\b\d{3}\b\s*(.*?)\s*Adónem számlaszáma: (\S*)` [in action](https://regex101.com/r/N1kBs6/1/). Else, I think `\b\d{3}\b\s*((?:(?!\b\d{3}\b)[^])*?)\s*Adónem számlaszáma: (\S*)` will work. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/N1kBs6/2).

Comment: @braX I am using RegEx in Excel VBA, but you are right, the problem is not related to VBA in any way, I have removed the tag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it works! :)

Comment: @MilánForgách: even if the problem is not related to VBA, it's always usefull to put the language (or tool) in which regex is used since features and behaviors may differ between them. (This is also explicitly recommended in the description of the regex tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to match across lines, you may get it done with

```vb
\b\d{3}\b\s*(.*?)\s*Adónem számlaszáma: (\S*)
```

See [this regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/N1kBs6/1).

Otherwise, you would need to make sure there are no other 3-digit numbers between a 3-digit number and your fixed string:

```vb
\b\d{3}\b\s*((?:(?!\b\d{3}\b)[\s\S])*?)\s*Adónem számlaszáma: (\S*)
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/N1kBs6/3).  Let me explain the second pattern as it is more specific:

- `\b\d{3}\b` - three digits enclosed with word boundaries
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `((?:(?!\b\d{3}\b)[\s\S])*?)` - Group 1: any char (`[\s\S]`), zero or more repetitions but as few as possible (`*?`), that does not start a 3-digit number enclosed with word boundaries
- `Adónem számlaszáma:`  - a fixed string
- `(\S*)` - Group 2: zero or more non-whitespace chars.

Comment: Thank you, the second pattern works perfectly. However, Excel throws me an error using the pattern. I know that the scope of the question was not about VBA, but may I ask for a VBA compatible pattern? Or should I submit another question? Thank you!

Comment: @MilánForgách Actually, it should be working there, but let's replace `[^]` with `[\s\S]`. Also, note you may have trouble with `ó` and `á` chars, but hopefully  it will do.